# Delete from two tables with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How can I delete rows from two different tables in one single query?
Part of the query is: WHERE Lendings.Id = (the id I want to delete)

The Column "ProductId" refer to the "Id" column in the Products table.

```
Table: Lendings
Id - ProductId

Table: Products
Id - Name
```

EDIT:

I do this instead :)

```
function DeleteLending($lendingid, $productid)
{
    global $conn; 
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Lendings WHERE Id = ?; DELETE FROM Products WHERE Id = ?;";
    $params = array($lendingid, $productid);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
}
```

Comment: @Strawberry INNOdb tables for "sql-server"?

Comment: `DeleteLending()` indicates you want to delete Lending primarily. Why does it result in deletion of the Product as well? I have a solution but I need to understand your requirements first.

Comment: It's just the name of the function. I delete lending + product in the sql statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

DELETE only deletes from one table at a time. You can, however, use the join clauses to delete in one table, depending on data in another table, but you cannot delete from two tables in one statement.

Issue two delete statements.

Comment: Okay. Then It need know what Row It should delete in the Products table. Maybe with a select query.

Comment: WHERE Products.Id = Lendings.ProductId

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I use two statements.